# a particular action when Receive intent by using List View in android studio

Tags: android, listview

i,m android programming , i have 2 activity.
activity one is contain List View 
activity two is contain : 2 `Edit Text` and`Image View`

there is code XML for activity one :

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nameList"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/refuresh" />

<Button
    android:text="add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addlist"
    android:onClick="moveto"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />

<Button
    android:text="refrus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/refuresh"
    android:onClick="refrush"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addlist"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="27dp" />
```

there is activity 2 :

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/textheare"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/notimg"
       />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Finish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/Fin" />
```

in activity one contain 2 Button : `add` and `refrus` 
when click a button `add` moves to activate 2

in activity two contain 1 Button: `Finish`
when click a button `Finish` Stores the data In the `Edit_Text` by SQL Lite
and go to Activity one

when click a button `refrus` Is located in activity one , List appears in data was stored in activity 2

i want on click the list , move to activity 2 and show the data was stored ?

Answer (score 0):

*May Be This will help to u.dynamically we can add data use this code*

```
MainActivity.java
```

listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

```
    dBase=openOrCreateDatabase("invoicedb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor c=dBase.query("company_new", new String[]{"clientname","cphone","cemail","caddress","cfax"}, null, null, null, null, null);

    while(c.moveToNext()){


        arrayList.add(c.getString(0));
        arrayList1.add(c.getString(1));
        arrayList2.add(c.getString(2));
        arrayList3.add(c.getString(3));
        arrayList4.add(c.getString(4));

 }
    BaseAdapter2 adapter = new BaseAdapter2(ExistingContacts.this, arrayList, arrayList1,arrayList2,arrayList3,arrayList4);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

BaeeAdapter2:-

public class BaseAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Activity activity;
// private ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
private static ArrayList clientname,cphone,cemail,caddress,cfax;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;




public BaseAdapter2(Activity a, ArrayList r, ArrayList bod,ArrayList c,ArrayList d,ArrayList e) {
    activity = a;


    this.clientname = r;
    this.cphone=bod;
    this.cemail=c;
    this.caddress=d;
    this.cfax=e;



    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return clientname.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

    TextView clientname_new = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.clientname_hii); // title
    String song = clientname.get(position).toString();
    clientname_new.setText(song);


    TextView phone = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.clientphone);
    String song2 =cphone.get(position).toString();

    phone.setText(song2);

    TextView email = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.email);
    String song3 =cemail.get(position).toString();

    email.setText(song3);

    TextView address = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.address_new);
    String song4 =caddress.get(position).toString();

    address.setText(song4);

    TextView fax = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.fax);
    String song5 =cfax.get(position).toString();

    fax.setText(song5);


    vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position


            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ExistingPreview.class);
            TextView clientname=(TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.clientname_hii);
            TextView clientphone=(TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.clientphone);
            TextView email=(TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.email);
            TextView address_new=(TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.address_new);
            TextView fax=(TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.fax);

            String client_txt=clientname.getText().toString();
            String phone_txt=clientphone.getText().toString();
            String email_txt=email.getText().toString();
            String address_txt=address_new.getText().toString();
            String fax_txt=fax.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(activity,client_txt+"\n"+phone_txt+"\n"+email_txt+"\n"+address_txt+"\n"+fax_txt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            SharedPreferences spf=activity.getSharedPreferences("mypref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=spf.edit();
            editor.putString("client_hii",client_txt);
            editor.putString("clientphone_hii",phone_txt);
            editor.putString("email_hii",email_txt);
            editor.putString("address_hii",address_txt);
            editor.putString("fax_hii",fax_txt);
            editor.commit();

            activity.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    return vi;

}
```

}

Comment: i use Array Adapter

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Below Code for that

```
ListView lView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

String path="/storage/sdcard0/sample_images/";
File f=new File(path);
```

String[] files= f.list();
            (Or)
    String[] files=new Strin[]{"hi","hello","how r u"};
   ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                                                                `enter code here`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, files);
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I wan to switching from activity 2 . when click button add or click list  Both they move to the same activity 2 , but click add button to new list data and click list view to edit data was stored